# how to deploy custom SSIS Component in SSDT 2017 with sql server 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016, sql-server-data-tools

I am new to SSDT and i am creating a demo custom SSIS component on sql server data tools 2017
and i want to deploy that and want to test it in my SSIS project, but i don't know how to do so
i have referred old documentation but it is for old visual studio and sql server, in this case i am not understanding that procedure to deploy the component.

Please help me out with this

I have created the assembly signing as per the following articles first point of deployment.

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/developing-a-custom-ssis-source-component/

i am not understanding the other steps how to and where to enter that commands

Please somebody help me out in this